# How unique are surveymonkey ids returned from the API?

Tags: surveymonkey

Are survey monkey ids globally unique? Unique within an account?

I'm storing surveymonkey results in a relational database and I'm wondering if I can use single ids (e.g. answer_id) as primary keys, or whether I need to use composite keys (e.g. (survey_id, question_id, answer_id)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer_id is globally unique among all SurveyMonkey answer_ids so a composite key is not required if you use that as your unique key for answers. The answer_id from one survey will not collide with any other answer_id from any SurveyMonkey survey. As sysmod mentioned, each ID type is in it's own domain so you can't count on them being unique across types.

Answer (score 2):

I asked this a while back, see the archives. As I recall the answer is that any given table is unique but you can't assume they are globally unique in the sense that for example a respondentid should not ever duplicate a question id.   One sequence may run over into another's some day.